# How to Create Shaving Foam in Blender 2.8

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I really need to create a shaving foam shot for my final university short film, if anyone can help me with some professional techniques here are the storyboard images : [image: as you can see the foam need to fall on a hand]

[image: Then it has to be already on the neck to start shaving]

Thanks in advance, 
Best regards.

Comment: try this link, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRg-JYXdB64

Comment: Also give the Flip Fluid add-on a look, it might help with the simulation of the motion.
https://blendermarket.com/products/flipfluids